# Translating a Google BigQuery query to Sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, google-bigquery

I have the following BigQuery query that works well:

```
SELECT created_at, actor_attributes_email, type FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
  WHERE 
  (repository_name="rubinius") AND
    (created_at CONTAINS '2011-') AND
  type !='WatchEvent'
ORDER BY created_at;
```

However, now I need to execute the same query in Sqlite3. What changes do I need to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The only nonstandard feature not supported by SQLite in this query is `CONTAINS`; replace it with `created_at LIKE '%2011-%'`, or if the value is guaranteed to begin with the year, with `created_at LIKE '2011-%'`.